# Mysql prepare statement - Select

Tags: php, mysql, prepare

Who can give me an advice? why the query can't to provide me an expected value? Thanks.

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($GLOBALS["mysql_host"], $GLOBALS["mysql_user"],          $GLOBALS["mysql_passwd"], $GLOBALS["mysql_database"]);
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT one FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
 $last = $stmt->bind_result($one);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 $mysqli->close();

 Echo $last; //it should be "abc"
```

Comment: Your question is "who can give me advice?". Well, only someone who understands what you need. For that, your question needs to be less vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to `execute` and then call `fetch` on `mysql_stmt`-objects.
Because you may get multiple results (rows).

With `fetch` you will advance your result-Cursor.

Documentation:
[mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli.php)
[mysqli-stmt](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli-stmt.php)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name LIMIT 5")) {
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can.
An advise would be plain and simple: **do not use mysqli**

Use **[PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)** instead

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT one FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$last = $stmt->fetchColumn();

echo $last; //it should be "abc"
```

clean, simple and **works**

Comment: What's wrong with MySQLi?

Comment: indeed, i would prefer PDO too. 
It has a nice level of abstraction. 
There is a [nice explanation at nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)