# Parametrized queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$postid = $_GET['p'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=:postid");
$stmt->bindValue(':postid', $postid);
$stmt->execute();

while($postRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
    $posts[] = $postRows;
}
```

The above code does not work.

Usually I'd do:

```
$postid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['p']);
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id='$postid'");

while($postRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $posts[] = $postRows;
}
```

which works for me.

I can't seem to get my head around this because online explanations do a poor job of actually explaining how to do these, so I have been using `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead but I understand it can be vulnerable.
 Can anyone help me understand how to properly do these queries?

Comment: I think you're mixing between mysqli prepared statements and PDO

Comment: Refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: @EhabEldeeb *"I think you're mixing between mysqli prepared statements and PDO"* - Not "think" but "are" and they should not mix MySQL APIs. They need to use the same API from connection to query. We also don't know whether they are connecting with PDO or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is how it's connecting http://puu.sh/jhkf8/5ad98cd995.png

Comment: well there you go. As I said above, you need to use the same API from connection to query. This isn't *rum & coke* ;-)

Comment: What is it using lol? I'm not familiar with mysqli, PDO, object-oriented, procedural terms etc

Comment: I posted my answer for you below. You'll make it ;-) @frosty

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=:postid");
  $stmt->bindValue(':postid', $postid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:[Mysql prepare statement - Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085109/mysql-prepare-statement-select)

And an Example from PHP on using `bindValue()`website(http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php example#2):

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindValue(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

In this example they are specifying `parameter type` in the `bindValue()` statement such as `PDO::PARAM_STR` and `PDO::PARAM_INT`. You too try specifying your parameter as such.

Or you can also prepare statements and bind values using `bindParam(':placeholder',$variable_or_value);` (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Prepared statements are used for executing same query multiple times with different or changing values. It gives more efficiency. For simple or random queries there is no need to prepare statements infact it will only decrease the effificeny b creating overheads for preparations. And prepared statements are generally applied on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do might be:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?');
//Use 's' for a string or 'i' for an integer
$stmt->bind_param('s', $postid);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{ }
```

Comment: All the HTML below this seems to not load. If I delete it, the HTML loads. What's that a sign of? PHP error?

Comment: Could you share the part of your code where the problem occurs ?

Comment: Sure, I have HTML then use php tags - http://puu.sh/jhktt/72d1b40302.png - then the HTML continues

Comment: I just tested it by deleting bits to see. It appears this is the problem `$result = $stmt->get_result();`

Comment: Can you try : `$stmt->store_result(); $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;` Just before get_result()

Comment: That seems to break it too.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`

Comment: According to the PHP documentation, `get_result` is defined since 5.3.0, and you have 5.6.0. So, you might have a problem with your PHP installation, or something (I might be wrong)

Comment: this is all very strange and annoying

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, you are mixing MySQL APIs (mysqli_ and PDO).

You need to use the same API from connecting to querying. Those different APIs do not intermix.

In order to use PDO, you need to:

- Connect using PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
- Query with PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Then if you want to use PDO with prepared statements:

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

You cannot connect with `mysqli_` then mix MySQL functions with PDO.

*That's how it rolls.*

---

Footnotes:

If you want to stick with `mysqli_`, then it too has prepared statements.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

*The choice is yours*. Remember to use the same MySQL API.

---

Error checking:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - if using all PDO
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - If using all MySQLi

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.